# Get the time from a string datetime that have special characters

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get the time from this string `2017-11-07 16:56:34.787-08` while using the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_string = '2017-11-07 16:56:34.787-08'
dt = datetime.strptime(my_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

However `my_string` is slightly unique as it is appended with `-08` that is appended behind, and at times it can be in 3-digits form eg. `-123`
Instead of doing a roundabout method, using split('-') then remove the last element, is there a better method that I can get the time directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), which will avoid having to [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) result (since the date contains other dashes).

```
from datetime import datetime

my_string = '2017-11-07 16:56:34.787-08'
date_string, _ = my_string.rsplit('-', 1)
dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

print(dt)
# 2017-11-07 16:56:34.787000
```

There is no way to use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) with characters to ignore, date string and format [must match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime):

> If *string* [...] has excess data after parsing, `ValueError` is raised.